# pyspark connection to MariaDB fails with ClassNotFoundException

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, mariadb

I'm trying to retrieve data from MariaDB with pyspark.

I created spark_session with configuration to include jdbc jar file, but couldn't solve problem. Current code to create session looks like below.

```py
path = "hdfs://nameservice1/user/PATH/TO/JDBC/mariadb-java-client-2.7.1.jar"
# or path = "/home/PATH/TO/JDBC/mariadb-java-client-2.7.1.jar"

spark = SparkSession.config("spark.jars", path)\
        .config("spark.driver.extraClassPath", path)\
        .config("spark.executor.extraClassPath", path)\
        .enableHiveSupport()
        .getOrCreate()
```

Note that I've tried every case of configuration I know
(Check Permission, change directory both hdfs or local, add or remove configuration ...)

And then, code to load data is.

```py
sql = "SOME_SQL_TO_RETRIEVE_DATA"

spark = spark.read.format('jdbc').option('dbtable', sql)
        .option('url', 'jdbc:mariadb://{host}:{port}/{db}')\
        .option("user", SOME_USER)
        .option("password", SOME_PASSWORD)
        .option("driver", 'org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver')
        .load()
```

But it fails with `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver`

When I tried this with `spark-submit`, I saw log message.

```
... INFO SparkContext: Added Jar /PATH/TO/JDBC/mariadb-java-client-2.7.1.jar at spark://SOME_PATH/jars/mariadb-java-client-2.7.1.jar with timestamp SOME_TIMESTAMP
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who suffers from same problem.

I figured out. [Spark Document](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#runtime-environment) says that

> *Note:* In client mode, this config must not be set through the SparkConf directly in your application, because the driver JVM has already started at that point. Instead, please set this through the --driver-class-path command line option or in your default properties file.

So instead setting configuration on python code, I added arguments on `spark-submit` following [this document](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.0/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html#content).

```sh
spark-submit {other arguments ...} \ 
--driver-class-path PATH/TO/JDBC/my-jdbc.jar \
--jars PATH/TO/JDBC/my-jdbc.jar \
MY_PYTHON_SCRIPT.py
```